# How do I edit the Text value of a textbox? (roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a small little game in roblox. The local script im using is inside the workspace, so this isnt as easy as simply writing `local textbox = script.Parent`
I need the full path to this textbox. It's name is `TextBox` and right now I have:

```lua
local button = script.Parent

button.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function ()
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.TextBox.Text = "this is a test"
end)
```

When I run this code, and click the in game obj button, it gives me this error: `Workspace.button.click.OnClick:4: attempt to index nil with 'PlayerGui'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is likely because you are calling the `.MouseClick` function from a server side script, while `game.Players.LocalPlayer` can only be called from a LocalScript. In order to get the player who clicked the `ClickDetector` you can do:

```
local button = script.Parent

button.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player) --Player param gives the player (in game.Players) who clicked the Click Detector
     player.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.TextBox.Text = "this is a test"
end)
```

Comment: This solution worked thank you! I made the script as a local script in roblox studio so I would have never thought of it being a server-side issue